# How to remove only one style property with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with this property `style="-moz-user-select:none; position:static !important;"`.
I need to remove the `-moz-user-select`
Tried with `$(selector).css()` but I don't know what value to set because it's `"none"`.

Comment: If it is `none` why do you need to remove it? If you need to change it to another value [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select) is a list of valid values

Answer (score 272, accepted):

The documentation for [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) says that setting the style property to the empty string will remove that property if it does not reside in a stylesheet:

> Setting the value of a style property
> to an empty string — e.g.
> `$('#mydiv').css('color', '')` — removes
> that property from an element if it
> has already been directly applied,
> whether in the HTML style attribute,
> through jQuery's `.css()` method, or
> through direct DOM manipulation of the
> style property. It does not, however,
> remove a style that has been applied
> with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or
> `<style>` element.

Since your styles are inline, you can write:

```
$(selector).css("-moz-user-select", "");
```

Comment: @KevinFegan `document.getElementById('mydiv').style.removeProperty('-moz-user-select')`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about jQuery, but want to add (for those like myself, who stumble here from Google) a solution with vanilla js:

*(Based on my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/94280c85050274881813bbfe27c6a121)*)

Below is a breakdown of the method, but removing the comments and it's pretty much small and simple one-liner **split->filter->join**

```js
const removeStyleProp = (elm, prop) => 
  elm.style.cssText = elm.style.cssText // "top: 0px; bottom: 50px; text-align: right;"
    .split('; ') // ["top: 0px", "bottom: 50px", "right: 2px", "text-align: right;"]
    .filter(p => !p.startsWith(prop) ) // ["top: 0px", "bottom: 50px", "text-align: right;"]
    .join(';');

// usage:
removeStyleProp(test, 'right')
console.log( test.style.cssText )
```

```html
<div id='test' style='top:0;right:5px;bottom:50px;right:2px;text-align:right;'></div>
```

Alternately could also be done with Regex

Answer (score -3):

You can also replace "-moz-user-select:none" with "-moz-user-select:inherit". This will inherit the style value from any parent style or from the default style if no parent style was defined.

Comment: inheriting is not removing