# Remove margin-right jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using sortable, I need to remove the margin-right and not just leave it as 0. I have problems if you use margin-right 0 to sortable.
He wins by default margin by jquery. So no use class change, and can not use remove.attr ("style"), because would remove all the CSS.

Comment: would `margin: -1` work?

Comment: I'm using jquery sortable, elements change position.

Comment: Try the solution in this related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951365/how-to-remove-only-one-style-property-with-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('selector').css('margin-right', '');
```

Comment: This works if you have jQuery set the margin-right initially but if it is in CSS i.e. `.fred{margin-right:4em; margin-left:6px; border:solid green 1px; display:inline-block;}` it would fail to actually remove and would get set to `4em` in this example.  Which is known and documented, see comment on the question. http://jsfiddle.net/e9Y28/ - I tested using Chrome

Comment: Well, that's not the case here. If he had set the margin in CSS, then he could just remove it.

Comment: this code did not work for me. $('selector').css('margin-right', '0px'); did however. In my case the margin was set in a style sheet, on the 'body' selector