# Removing a specific style property from element

Tags: jquery, html, css, properties, styles

There's a div in my page that gets styling from my company's custom CSS files. Some of this styling messes up how my div is displayed/positioned. I tracked it down to being a `display: inline-block;`.

Using Chrome developer tool's elements tab, when I deselect this specific line, my element displays properly:

[image: Just to make it clear what I'm doing in Chrome which provides the results I'm looking for]

So I figured I'd override the property to display's default value `display: inline !important;` to simulate "removing" the property. The property was overriden, but my element was still misaligned.

I also tried using jQuery after the element was loaded: `$('#myelement').css('display', 'X');` where X is any acceptable value for the display property. I also tried an empty space. None provided the results that unchecking (removing?) the property in the Chrome developer tools did.

So what options do I have left to simulate unchecking the style property in Chrome dev tool's element tab? I assume the closest thing would be to somehow remove the property from my element, but I'm not sure how to do this, as this property is defined in an external CSS file which I'm not allowed to modify.

Comment: can you post some code or recreate in a fiddle?

Comment: Did you try just editing the CSS file `

Comment: The default display mode for a `div` is `block`. So maybe `display:block !important;`?

Comment: This should help `:)` => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951365/how-to-remove-only-one-style-property-with-jquery

Comment: @GaryStorey Holy... this worked. This is what I get for trusting what w3schools has listed as the default value: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp


-- meta: how do I mark this as resolved?

Comment: @niebula w3schools is notorious for spreading bad information.  Use MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The default display mode for a `div` is `block`. So maybe `display:block !important;`?" - Gary Storey

(Answer given as actual answer so the post could be marked as answered.)

Comment: Followup: does "initial value" differ from "default value"? [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and [Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) both show the initial/default value to be "inline", which is where I got my assumptions from.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp look at that. Well the default value for a <p> or <a> tag would actually be `inline` so it isn't quite wrong, for a `div` however the default or initial value is `block`

Answer (score 0):

The default `display` value for a `div` is `block`.  So you should set the value to be:

```
div { display:block; }
```

If for some reason that doesn't work, you could try overriding by adding an additional element to increase the specificity.  For example:

```
/*specificity value of 2 */
body div { display: block; }

/* or specificity value of 11 */
.content div {display: block; }

 /* or specificity value of 101 */
 #content div
```

This increases the specificity of the selector allowing you to override the current values without making it impossible to override later.  More information can be found [in this article](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), and [this site](http://cssspecificity.com/).

Only use the `!important`  if none of the above doesn't work.  `!important` should always be the very last option! Only another `!important` can override itself with leads to really bad code.

To learn more about the initial/default values of elements you can refer to [this article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/).